# Laravel Guzzle error -- cURL error 7: Failed to connect

Tags: api, client, guzzle

I am trying to get response from an api using GuzzleHttp but it is showing error cURL error 7: Failed to connect to ***********.com port 8009 after 569 ms: Connection refused .Below is my controller function . How to solve this issue

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class DailyAttendanceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET', '**************', ['auth' =>  ['', '']]);
        $result = $res->getBody();  
        $data = json_decode($result,true);
    }
}
```